# Rounded Rectangles

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, geometry

## Challenge

Given an integer greater or equal to 4, n, print a rounded rectangle of as close as possible (with a gap of 1) sides and a perimeter of n characters.

## Rules

- n is always 4 or greater, because otherwise the output wouldn't be a square
- The characters for the perimeter can be any non-whitespace character
- The rectangle should have equal sides when possible
- When not possible, the rectangle can be up to one character taller or wider than its other side
- The rectangle should have one whitespace character in each corner
- The rectangle can only ever have a gap of 1 (excluding corners) along the entire perimeter
- The gap can be on any side and any position along the perimeter

## Rules

Least amount of bytes wins!

## Examples

```
Input: 4
Output:
 o
o o
 o

Input: 5
Output:
 oo
o  o
 o

Input: 8
Output:
 oo
o  o
o  o
 oo

Input: 21
Output:
 oooooo
o      o
o      o
o      o
o      o
o      o
 ooooo
```

Here is the python3 code I used to generate the above examples:

> ```
> import math
>
> ch = 'o'
>
> def print_rect(p):
>     side_length = math.ceil(p / 4)
>     height = side_length
>     remainder = p - side_length * 3
>     p = side_length + 2
>
>     if side_length - remainder >= 2 or not remainder:
>         remainder += 2
>         height -= 1
>
>     lines = [(ch * side_length).center(p)]
>     for i in range(height):
>         lines.append(ch + ch.rjust(side_length + 1))
>     lines.append((ch * remainder).center(p))
>
>     print('Output:')
>     for line in lines:
>         print(line)
>
> print_rect(int(input('Input: ')))
> ```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
def f(n):t=(n+3)/4;c,s='o ';h=(n-t+1)/3;print'\n'.join([s+c*t]+[c+s*t+c]*h+[s+c*(n-t-h-h)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xEoMgEAB7X3EdnCdxxFQyvsRQZIgEUhwO0OT1xNjuzO4e3xoS69ZeuwcvGZe6SqYZx7txQ1lFAmHCiVSlCcfZHDlyFQ8Wt0@KLLdCrq@WNkelr@RsH@hif0MFFdBi8ylDhMiQn/ze5TRojUt37iJ2cAXbDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
Ｆ⁴«×o⁺÷Ｉθ⁴﹪÷﹪Ｉθ⁴Ｘ²↔⊖ι²¶↷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU09C8IwFJz1V4RMrxAHSzcnsYuDEMTRpTZP@yDNwySNg/jbYxQFPTiO@4Drh8733Nmcz@wFNJW4z2fak4twoBEDSJZKaDsF2LrYUiKDsOlChGulRFO4YzNZ/mk/wd9I8w091EqsTwFa7D2O6CIaoKpAifolq@@zPDr5dpQ47ukyRCj2kXO9zItknw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Loop over the four sides of the rounded rectangle.

```
×o⁺
```

Print a number of `o`s given by the sum of...

```
÷Ｉθ⁴
```

... one quarter of the input as a number, rounded down, and...

```
﹪÷﹪Ｉθ⁴Ｘ²↔⊖ι²
```

... add an extra `o` a) on both horizontal sides if the input has a remainder (modulo 4) of 2 or 3, and b) on the first vertical side if the input is odd.

```
¶
```

Omit the corner.

```
↷
```

Pivot ready for the next side.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 143

```
n=>(x=Math.floor(n/4),q=n%2==1?x+1:x,` ${"o".repeat(q)} 
${Array(n%4==2||n%4==3?x+1:x).fill(`o${" ".repeat(q)}o`).join`\n`}
 ${"o".repeat(x)}`)
```

Comment: `q=n%2==1?x+1:x` -> `q=n%2+x`; `.repeat` -> `[R='repeat']`; `Array..fill..join` -> `...[R]`; `floor -> (no need, String#repeat would do floor)`; [Tio](https://tio.run/##ZYrBCoJAFEX3fsXbyMzjlZG5iOz1ByLoooUIIzaGITOi0ib69mlsWat77zn30TybuZ36cdkae9OuA3aGL7JkAQJJ5iyswKpgMelRN4uoZcZmlyCpQHlNZVXU8srRkTKkfKW4kuiwbmUDtS4TJswxUkn5946usxPIQS/QA0OS@jgz7GNfiBBeAUBrzWwHHQ32LkVoT2IDPaY/opM9/kEP3u4D)